# How can we fill a flash form in Python

Tags: python, forms, flash, internet-explorer-8, pywin32

Again a stupid question by me, The title says everything, I want to fill a flash form using python! I can open IE but I don't know how to fill information to that form because its flash, When I try to see the HTTP POSTS its all messed up, I have even tried opening that post in python with simple urllib opener or the mechanize library and they doesn't work it just hang my python IDLE window! I'm using pythoncom/win32.client for opening IE, Please let me know if I can fill a flash form in python or make any clicks in the flash forms using IE/python.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/?